# How to disable write protection on ARM64

Tags: linux, arm64

Currently, I need write at protected memory for syscall hooking. In x86, we can disable protection by clean `cr0`. How about on ARM64(aarch64), anything similar?

Comment: The WP bit exists on x86 to improve copy-on-write functionality.  Disabling it will likely dramatically hurt performance.  And I don't believe you can adjust this on ARM64 except by adjusting the page table entry, so unless you actually want to break read-only pages (and the OS), you'll probably need to find another solution.

Comment: You can turn off the MMU if you feel very daring...